# excel date format not inserting in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

in my project i inserted data using excel sheet but i can't inserted date format data to mysql. here's my code. i have given full code for better understanding. dob and join_date are in date formate.

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']))
    header('location:../../');
else {
    if((!isset($_POST['streamId']) || $_POST['streamId'] =='')
    || (!isset($_POST['branchId']) || $_POST['branchId'] =='')
    || (!isset($_POST['batchId']) || $_POST['batchId'] =='')
    || (!isset($_POST['divisionId']) || $_POST['divisionId'] =='')
    || (!isset($_POST['semId']) || $_POST['semId'] =='')) {
        header('location:../../views/student/list.php');
    }
    $tmp = explode(".", $_FILES["studnetExcel"]["name"]);
    if((strcmp($tmp[1], 'xls')!=0) && (strcmp($tmp[1], 'xlsx')!=0)) {
        echo "string";
    }
    else {
        require_once('../../config/connection.php');
        $streamResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM streams WHERE streams_id='".$_POST['streamId']."' ");
        $branchResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM branches WHERE streams_id='".$_POST['streamId']."' AND branches_id='".$_POST['branchId']."' ");
        $batchResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM batches WHERE streams_id='".$_POST['streamId']."' AND branches_id='".$_POST['branchId']."' AND  batches_id='".$_POST['batchId']."'");
        $divisionResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM division WHERE division_id='".$_POST['divisionId']."' ");
        $semResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM edu_system WHERE streams_id='".$_POST['streamId']."' AND edu_sys_id='".$_POST['semId']."' ");
        if((mysql_num_rows($streamResult) == 1) && (mysql_num_rows($branchResult) == 1) && (mysql_num_rows($batchResult) == 1) && (mysql_num_rows($divisionResult) == 1) && (mysql_num_rows($semResult) == 1)) {
            require_once '../../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES["studnetExcel"]["tmp_name"]);
            $value='';
            foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
                $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
                $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
                $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
                $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
                $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
                for ($row = 4; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
                    $value.="(NULL,".$_POST['streamId'].",".$_POST['branchId'].",".$_POST['batchId'].",".$_POST['divisionId'].",".$_POST['semId'].",";
                    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
                        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                        if($col==$highestColumnIndex-1) {
                            $value .= "'".$cell->getValue()."',";
                            $value .= $_SESSION['role']['id'].","."'active'";
                        }
                        else {
                            if($row>2 && str_replace(' ', '', $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, 1)->getValue())=="JoinDate")
                                $value .= "'".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($cell->getValue()))."',";
                            else
                                $value .= "'".$cell->getValue()."',";
                        }
                    }
                    $value .= '),';
                }
            }
            if(mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO students(students_id,streams_id,branches_id,batches_id,division_id,edu_sys_id,annrl_no,first_name,middle_name,last_name,address1,city,state,pincode,address2,gender,cast,blood_group,contact,dob,email,join_date,password,p_contact,p_email,added_by,status) VALUES".substr($value, 0,-1))) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "STUDENT SUCCESSFULY ADDED";
                header("location:../../views/student/add.php?streamId=".$_POST['streamId']."&branchId=".$_POST['branchId']."&batchId=".$_POST['batchId']."&divisionId=".$_POST['divisionId']."&semId=".$_POST['semId']);
            }
            else {
                if(mysql_errno() == 1062) {
                    $inc=-1;
                    if(preg_match('/email/', mysql_error())) {
                        $inc++;$_SESSION['notify'][$inc] = "STUDENT/PARENTS EMAIL IS ALREADY EXISTED";
                        header("location:../../views/student/add.php?streamId=".$_POST['streamId']."&branchId=".$_POST['branchId']."&batchId=".$_POST['batchId']."&divisionId=".$_POST['divisionId']."&semId=".$_POST['semId']);
                    }
                    else if(preg_match('/annrl_no/', mysql_error())) {
                        $inc++;$_SESSION['notify'][$inc] = "ENROLMENT NUMBERs REPEATED";
                        header("location:../../views/student/add.php?streamId=".$_POST['streamId']."&branchId=".$_POST['branchId']."&batchId=".$_POST['batchId']."&divisionId=".$_POST['divisionId']."&semId=".$_POST['semId']);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    echo mysql_errno();
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            header("location:../../views/student/add.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and my excel sheet is.
[image: excel]

i am getting 0000-00-00 for all record in dob and join_date.

Comment: What MySQL command is created in your PHP?

Comment: above php code...that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, an Excel "date" is an MS serialized timestamp, a measure of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if created on the Apple Mac version of MS Excel).... this is not a unix timestamp, nor is it a formatted date string.

PHPExcel provides a number of methods for converting this date to either a unix timestamp, or to a PHP DateTime object that you can then format for entry into an SQL statement.

Assuming that this is the case, then for columns `N` and `P`, you'd need to use

```
$dto = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cell->getValue());
```

and then you can use the DateTime object's `format()` method to convert to a `Y-m-d` formatted string

or

```
$dto = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue());
```

to convert to a unix timestamp, that can then be formatted using `date()`

Comment: You know the bit where you do `$value .= "'".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($cell->getValue()))."',";`.... that's what you need to change...... though you really should be using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables..... it is 2016 now, not 1996

Comment: i am dumb in php with excel so please help me with replacing this i have no idea how to replace this.